# How to compile for the Tiva C Launchpad using debian toolchain?

Tags: embedded, arm, debian

I'm trying to build code for the Tiva C Series TM4C123G Launchpad, but, when compiling on Debian "jessie" using "gcc-arm-none-eabi" toolchain there is a compilation error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/include/stdint.h: 
fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next
```

I've seen a similar issue here: [github/libopncm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/pull/249).

I've managed to build code using [the ARM toolchain on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) but I'd rather use the debian one or, at least, understand why it can't be used.

Comment: Did you see the comment "For Debian I've found that "gcc-arm-none-eabi" recommends "libnewlib-arm-none-eabi", but Debian "jessie" (testing) repo doesn't have such a package yet" ?

Comment: why don't you patch your local repo as suggested so it builds? or use system parameter when invoking gcc...

Comment: I'm not trying to compile libopncm3 but the Texas Instruments libraries so the patch doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the comment, but libnewlib-arm-none-eabi still is not available in jessie, and as it is a recommended package, it shouldn't prevent the toolchain to be used (or it would be a dependency).

Comment: I was wrong, I've installed libnewlib-arm-none-eabi from sid and the error is gone. Thanks for pointing it, auselen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed libnewlib-arm-none-eabi from sid and the error is gone.

```
aptitude install libnewlib-arm-none-eabi/sid
```

(You need to add a sid repository to your /etc/apt/sources.list file to use the above command)

Read the comments to the question for reference.